# Why are the drawables not appearing in card view for grid layout?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-cardview, android-gridlayout

I started learning grid view recently, but I cannot find the images from the drawable appearing on the cards. A white background is appearing on these cards instead. How can I make the drawable images appear ? I will also attach the screen shot of the activity right now.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDPFa.png) This is my XML Code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="10"
tools:context=".Main2Activity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textGrid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:fontFamily="serif-monospace"
        android:text="@string/grid"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="34sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>

<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="9"
    android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
    android:padding="14dp"
    android:rowCount="3">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:contentDescription="@string/name1"
                android:src="@drawable/mechanic" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/mechanic"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:contentDescription="@string/name2"
                android:src="@drawable/doctor" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/doctor"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:contentDescription="@string/name3"
                android:src="@drawable/electrician" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/electrician"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:src="@drawable/plumber"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:contentDescription="@string/name4" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/plumber"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:src="@drawable/driver"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:contentDescription="@string/name5"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/driver"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:src="@drawable/hospital"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:contentDescription="@string/name6"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/hospital"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</GridLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of setting `ImageView` height and width to 0dp. Set them to `wrap_content` or size that you want. Also set the `LinearLayout` height and width to `match_parent`.

Comment: Can I also know how make the text views under each drawable in the cards to appear in the activity ?

Comment: Yes, using RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout is an easy way.